# Linux serial port communication - Writing time adjustment

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded, embedded-linux

I'm new with Embedded Linux. I m trying to do an IR transmitter with only UART on my chip. I managed to obtain 38 khz pulse wave with single Uart. But in order to writing desired bytes to adjust something via infrared i m having some troubles with timing. For example , I want to do 1.4 ms logic high pulse and 0.5 ms logic low(that means logical 1 frame for an infrared system) so my code is like:

```
write(fd,buffer,8);  //that means 1.4 ms for pulse to be HIGH
usleep(500);        // 0.5 ms to wait
```

Then I want to write a single byte like "0xF0" so :

```
 Byte_Write_For_IRDevice(char byte_v)
 {
    int bitcount;
    char t=0;

    for(bitcount=0;bitcount<8;bitcount++)
    {
      int t=byte_v&1;
      byte_v>>=1;

      if(t==1)        //Logic '1' frame
      {
        write(fd,buffer,8);  //that means 1.4 ms for pulse to be HIGH

        usleep(500);        //0.5 ms for wait
      }
      else            //Logic '0' frame
      {
        write(fd,buffer,4);  //that means 0.7 ms for pulse to be HIGH

        usleep(500);  
      }

   }
 }
```

When I call this function usleep doesnt work exactly the time I want to wait. I used nanosleep, posix thread but they re not working both here is my openserialport function below. Where am i doing mistakes?

```
 int OpenSerialPort()
{

 /* Open and configure serial port */
 if ((fd = open(SERIALPORT,O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY)) == -1)
 {
    return -1;
 }
 struct termios options;
 struct serial_struct serinfo;


 // generating proper Baudrate to obtain 38 Khz freq. pulse wave on Uart
 speed = rate_to_constant(rate);

    if (speed == 0) {
       /* Custom divisor */
       serinfo.reserved_char[0] = 0;
       if (ioctl(fd, TIOCGSERIAL, &serinfo) < 0)
           return -1;
       serinfo.flags &= ~ASYNC_SPD_MASK;
       serinfo.flags |= ASYNC_SPD_CUST;
       serinfo.custom_divisor = (serinfo.baud_base + (rate / 2)) / rate;
       if (serinfo.custom_divisor < 1)
          serinfo.custom_divisor = 1;
       if (ioctl(fd, TIOCSSERIAL, &serinfo) < 0)
          return -1;
       if (ioctl(fd, TIOCGSERIAL, &serinfo) < 0)
          return -1;
       if (serinfo.custom_divisor * rate != serinfo.baud_base) {
              warnx("actual baudrate is %d / %d = %f",
                 serinfo.baud_base, serinfo.custom_divisor,
                 (float)serinfo.baud_base / serinfo.custom_divisor);
       }
   }

   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
   tcgetattr(fd, &options);
   cfsetispeed(&options, speed ?: B38400);
   cfsetospeed(&options, speed ?: B38400);
   cfmakeraw(&options);
   options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
   options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

   if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options) != 0)
   {
    //return -1;
   }


}
```

Comment: man 3 usleep: "The usleep() function suspends execution of the calling thread for (at least) usec microseconds.  The sleep may be lengthened slightly by any system activity or by the time spent processing the call or by the granularity of system timers."

Comment: Yes i read that too. But when i make usleep time longer the timing becomes correct. Also i tried nanosleep the mistake happened again.

Comment: Are you saying that it's not sleeping long enough? Are you assuming that the write call will take 1.4ms before it returns, and not return immediately?

Comment: No i want it smaller. And for the second question i want it to take 1.4 ms  so my buffer is having that time but delay doesnt work properly.

Comment: I don't understand. Your question explains what you're trying to do, but it doesn't say what happens instead and I don't understand your explanation. Can you edit it to say that, for example saying "I expected usleep to sleep 0.5ms, but instead what happens is (your observation here)"?

Comment: "... (that means logical 1 frame for an infrared system) ..." There exist many different serial transmission protocols using **I**nfra **R**red light and some of them use UART-compatible layer 1/2 transport. IR-Remote OTOH uses a 38kHz (and other) carrier, but is not UART-compatible. Which one are you actually talking about?

Comment: Such an exact timing in userspace and Linux? Hmmm.... Keep a scope nearby.

Comment: Such a time precision in userspace? I think you have to move linux to real time extention: full preempt kernel and [RATI](https://www.rtai.org/) or [Xenomai](http://xenomai.org/) for userspace.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I found a solution. The problem was i forgot approximately 100 us delay for each byte i transmit. When i added the delay problem solved.